# Glitch Between The Launch Screen and Initial Screen in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xib

Im trying to add an initial screen which would look like launch screen or splash screen.

Im experiencing a small glitch between those two screens.I have checked all my auto layout properties of label and image. They are the same.

Could anybody give me an insight on how to acheive this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: figured it out by my self. should by unchecking margin constraints for image

Answer (score 1):

Select Project->Target ->General 
and deselect default Launch Screen and select StoryBoard or Xib where u put your Initial Screen.[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but i figured it out that i have checked the margin constarints , by unchecking it looks fine now